# @Html display for and hidden for giving different values

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates

So in my editor template I have the following:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.IsSelected, new { @class = "CntIsSelected", @checked = Model.IsSelected })
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.value)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.value)
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.totalCount)
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the HTML it renders is...

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        <input class="CntIsSelected" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." id="CountryCount_0__IsSelected" name="CountryCount[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="CountryCount[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        CN
        <input id="CountryCount_0__value" name="CountryCount[0].value" type="hidden" value="JP">
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        30
    </td>
</tr>
```

The editor template gets it data from jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" name="SearchRecords_v1">
    function countryCounts(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/_CountryArea",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#CountryArea").html(partialViewResult);
                CountryIsSelectedClick();
                console.log(partialViewResult);
                },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Country ERROR!');
            }

        })
    }
</script>
```

On first render 'JP' is first on the list.  There are some options on the page then that will call that above jquery code and pass in some different parameters to the controller which will look up a new list from sql.

```
return PartialView("_CountryCounts", model);
```

Looking at the model it has the value of CN passing back and nothing else in this list (which is correct).

The display for shows the value of CN (this is correct) however the hidden for is showing the country code of JP which was the first value before the new list was generated.

It's like thew new list values are being updated but Hidden for isn't. It is keeping the old value for some reason...

Comment: Is JP the next element in your dataset after CN? Its worth adding your model and controller logic here too

Comment: yeah perhaps it isn't that simple, the values come from a ajax call actually. I'll look at that and post

Comment: JP is the first in the list for this example, if someone selects something from another list it fires an ajax call to get the new country data and uses

$("#CountryArea").html(partialViewResult)

to pass the new data to the editor template.  It looks like that isn't changing the value of the Hidden for

Comment: Sorry im a little confused by your response. What do you mean by 'someone selects something from another list'?

Comment: there are some check boxes on the page, if a user selects one, jquery sends the new parameters back to the action and gets different country counts from sql query.

return PartialView("_CountryCounts", model);

the model has the value CN on it in return, just checked...

however $("#CountryArea").html(partialViewResult); is showing the value JP!

Comment: Does the process make sense?

Comment: So it sounds like its getting two different datasets. It sounds like more of a JQuery issue to me.

Comment: it's an mvc issue it seems, ModelState.Clear(); in the controller fixes the "issue"

just found this and tested

Comment: thanks for looking at it though mate!

Comment: No problem, sorry it was just difficult to understand your question without more information on how your application was structured. Glad you discovered the error though.

Answer (score 2):

using this method, the model state must be cleared in the controller.

ModelState.Clear()

or as this is in a list, if you specifically want to clear one it seems

ModelState.Remove("CountryCount.value"); will work

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/20/aspnet-mvc-postbacks-and-htmlhelper-controls-ignoring-model-changes

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. You need to clear the model down before appending more data to it.